# django tenant: public schema not accessing public_urls.py after adding new tenant

Tags: python, django

I have a bizarre problem that I cannot seem to be able to solve after banging my head off the wall for a few hours now.

I am using django-tenant and after adding a new tenant, I cannot access my public schema. I get a 404 error because django is trying to find the URL outside of the public urls. I am getting somewhat confused about why this happens all of a sudden

here is attached my public_urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('register', registration),
    path('', login_view),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('documentation', documentation),
    

               ]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and in my settings:

```
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'inventory4.public_urls'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'inventory4.urls'
```

however when I access the url for my public schema, it seems to be now looking inside of `ROOT_URLCONF`
Note: static files are served well and well there in the proper folders.

I cant find out what is going, I am happy to add details to the post to better assist anyone who would have a clue on how to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing public_urls to urls in PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF?

**Ex.**

```
PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF = 'inventory4.urls'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'inventory4.urls'
```

You can try commenting out PUBLIC_SCHEMA_URLCONF and moving your urls to root.

Comment: thanks for your response, it is indeed what I did. completely forgot about it since then, but thanks anyways! this may be useful to someone else